# Given $\|A_i-B_i\|_F\leq \varepsilon$ estimate $\|A_1\cdot...\cdot A_m-B_1\cdot...\cdot B_m\|_\infty.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that we have matrices $A_1,...,A_m$ and $B_1,...,B_m$ such that $A_i, B_i\in\mathbb{R}^{p_i\times p_{i+1}}$ and $\|A_i-B_i\|_F\leq \varepsilon$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ (here $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes Frobenius norm of matrices).
Then what is the upper bound (in terms of $\varepsilon$) of the quantity
$$\|A_1\cdot...\cdot A_m-B_1\cdot...\cdot B_m\|_\infty,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the maximum absolute value of the entries of a matrix.

Comment: you should be able to construct a blocked argument to homogenize the nominal dimension -- i.e. so each is living in an $n \times  n$ matrix.  From there if you consider the special case of $n=1$ this becomes the Polynomial Product Inequality due to Weierstrass.  The proof for the $n \geq 2$ is essentially the same, as long as you work with a submultiplicative norm like the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c = \max\{\max_{i} \|A_i\|_F,\max_i \|B_i\|_F\}$. We note that
$$
A_1 A_2 \cdots A_{m-1}A_m - B_1 B_2 \cdots B_{m-1}B_m = \\
(A_1 A_2 \cdots A_{m-1}A_m - B_1 A_2 \cdots A_{m-1}A_m) + \cdots
+ (B_1 B_2 \cdots B_{m-1}A_m - B_1 B_2 \cdots B_{m-1}B_m).
$$
Note that the norm of any of the terms being added can be bounded using the inequality $\|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F \|B\|_F$ as follows. For example,
$$
\|B_1A_2A_3 \cdots A_n - B_1 B_2 A_3 \cdots A_m\|_F =\\
\|B_1(A_2 - B_2)A_3 \cdots A_m\|_F \leq\\
\|B_1\|_F\cdot \|A_2 - B_2\|_F\cdot \|A_3\|_F \cdots \|A_m\|_F \leq c^{m-1}\varepsilon.
$$

Noting that $\|A + B\|_F \leq \|A\|_F + \|B\|_F$, we can conclude that
$$
\|A_1 A_2 \cdots A_{m-1}A_m - B_1 B_2 \cdots B_{m-1}B_m\|_F \leq m \cdot c^{m-1}\varepsilon.
$$
Noting that $\|M\|_\infty \leq \|M\|_F$ for any matrix $M$, we can conclude that
$$
\|A_1 A_2 \cdots A_{m-1}A_m - B_1 B_2 \cdots B_{m-1}B_m\|_\infty \leq m \cdot c^{m-1}\varepsilon.
$$